# Mod_rewrite has different result on Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: windows, linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

I have set the following rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ core/index.php [L]
```

and the site architecture is

```
newsite
 ﹂ .htaccess
 ﹂ core
     ﹂ index.php
```

If I use the url: **http:// localhost/web/newsite/test** on Windows
it will redirect to **/web/newsite/core/index.php**
and it work!

but if use the url **http:// localhost/~user1/web/newsite/test** on Ubuntu
it will redirect to **/home/user1/public_html/web/newsite/core/index.php**
not **/~user1/web/newsite/core/index.php**

So, how can I solve this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `RewriteBase` above your rules:

```
RewriteBase /~user1/web/newsite/
```

Apache on ubuntu is tries to guess if the rewrite rule's target is a URI-path or a file-path and it's guessing incorrectly so you have to tell it what the real relative URI base is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I use RewriteBase, I have to set different RewriteBase in every Server.
So, are there any ways can solve the problem everywhere?

Comment: @AzureChen It shouldn't be redirecting at all, it should just be serving you the content.